# Include a php file and write the output to a file?

Tags: php

Rather than for the PHP code in content.php to be output to browser:

```
<?php

include 'content.php';
```

How to get the executed results not output to browser but to be written to a local text file:

```
<?php

include 'content.php';
// not output to browser
// but grab the results and write them to content.txt
```

How to do this?

Comment: Make the file return a variable and write that variable to a file.

Comment: I think you want `ob_get_contents`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) to capture the data and `file_put_contents()` to save the captured output.

```
ob_start();
include 'content.php';
$content = ob_get_clean();
file_put_contents('file.txt', $content);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set up the headers to download the file, and echo the contents of the file, using `file_get_contents`.

```
header('Content-type: text/plain');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="content.php"');
$html = file_get_contents('content.php');
echo $html;
```